# What exactly the arguments in setBufferPoolConfig mean?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to use The OpenCV BufferPool according to the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/d08/classcv_1_1cuda_1_1BufferPool.html) and I can't quite understand the arguments in some of its functions.

For example `setBufferPoolConfig` accepts three arguments, the second being stack size and the third stack count.

getBuffer (another function) gets called to allocate memory for a GpuMat like

```
GpuMat d_src1 = pool1.getBuffer(4096, 4096, CV_8UC1);
```

so it seems it is allocating 16MB for that GpuMat?? How can this be useful? In my case my images are only 282KB so isn't that too much?

So my question is how should I select the values of those parameters? Is there a good sample of use of those with actual images somewhere?